# Highcharts chart not showing in IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, highcharts, timeserieschart

i have made a Time Series chart with highcharts.

It works fine with FF, but it doesnt run in IE9. 
What could be the probleme here?

http://jsfiddle.net/sbra/tcFju/

Full code on jsfiddle: Snippet here:

```
   $(function () {
   $(document).ready(function() {
   var jsData = JSON.parse('{"data":[{"dateTime":1035151200001,"value":0.737},{"dateTime":1358722800001,"value":1.374},{"dateTime":1359327600001,"value":1.374},{"dateTime":1360537200001,"value":1.38}]}'.valueOf());
   console.log(jsData);
   var chartData = [];
   for (i in jsData.data) {
   chartData.push( [ new Date(jsData.data[i].dateTime).getTime(), jsData.data[i].value ] );
   }
   chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
   chart: {
   renderTo: 'tsc_chartDiv',
   zoomType: 'x',
   spacingRight: 20,
   spacingLeft: 20,
   marginLeft: 200
   },
   title: {
   text: 'xyz'
   },
   subtitle: {
   text: document.ontouchstart === undefined ?
   'Click and drag in the plot area to zoom in' :
   'Drag your finger over the plot to zoom in'
   },
   credits: { text: '-.com', href: '' },
   xAxis: {
   type: 'datetime',
   maxZoom: '1209600000', // fourteen days
   title: {
   text: null
   }
   },
   yAxis: {
   title: {
   text: ''
   },
   plotBands: [{
   color: 'rgba(253, 195, 156, .6)',
   from: 1.5,
   label: {
   text: 'High'
   },
   to: 1000},
   {
   from: 1.4,
   label: {
   text: 'Normaal'
   },
   to: 1.5},
   {
   color: 'rgba(196, 243, 112, .6)',
   from: 0,
   label: {
   text: 'Low'
   },
   to: 1.4}],
   showFirstLabel: false
   },
   tooltip: {
   shared: true
   },
   legend: {
   enabled: true
   },
   plotOptions: {
   area: {
   fillColor: {
   linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1},
   stops: [
   [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
   [1, 'rgba(2,0,0,0)']
   ]
   },
   lineWidth: 1,
   marker: {
   enabled: false,
   states: {
   hover: {
   enabled: true,
   radius: 5
   }
   }
   },
   shadow: false,
   states: {
   hover: {
   lineWidth: 1
   }
   },
   threshold: null
   }
   },
   series: [{
   type: 'area',
   name: 'xyz',
   data: chartData
   }]
   });
   var startx = 0;
   var starty = 20;
   var roundedVal = 0;
   chart.renderer.text('Index (I) Änderung:', startx + 20, starty + 20).add();
   roundedVal = (Math.round(parseFloat("0.004366812227074135")*1000)/10).toFixed(1);
   console.log(roundedVal);
   if (roundedVal >= 0.1) {
   chart.renderer.image("images/chart/up.png", startx + 20, starty + 40, 50, 50).add();
   }
   else if (!(roundedVal>=-0.1)) {
   chart.renderer.image("images/chart/down.png", startx + 20, starty + 40, 50, 50).add();
   } else {
   chart.renderer.image("images/chart/equal.png", startx + 20, starty + 40, 50,        50).add();
   }
   chart.renderer.text(roundedVal + "%", startx + 100, starty + 75).css({
   fontWeight: 'bold',
   fontSize: '20px',
   }).add();
   chart.renderer.text('I-Aktuell:', startx + 20, starty + 120).add();
   roundedVal = (Math.round(parseFloat("1.38")*1000)/1000).toString();
   chart.renderer.text(roundedVal, startx + 20, starty + 160).css({
   fontWeight: 'bold',
   fontSize: '30px',
   }).add();
   chart.renderer.text('I-Zuletzt:', startx + 20, starty + 200).add();
   roundedVal = (Math.round(parseFloat("1.374")*1000)/1000).toString();
   chart.renderer.text(roundedVal, startx + 100, starty + 200).add();
   chart.renderer.text('I-Höchst:', startx + 20, starty + 220).add();
   roundedVal = (Math.round(parseFloat("1.466")*1000)/1000).toString();
   chart.renderer.text(roundedVal, startx + 100, starty + 220).add();
   chart.renderer.text('I-Tiefst:', startx + 20, starty + 240).add();
   roundedVal = (Math.round(parseFloat("0.685")*1000)/1000).toString();
   chart.renderer.text(roundedVal, startx + 100, starty + 240).add();
   chart.renderer.text('I-AVG:', startx + 20, starty + 260).add();
   roundedVal = (Math.round(parseFloat("1.0567862745098051")*1000)/1000).toString();
   chart.renderer.text(roundedVal, startx + 100, starty + 260).add();
   });
   });
```

Thx 
stefan

Comment: It works for me in IE9. What error did you get?

Comment: no error it silently didn't show up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the problem is

```
console.log(jsData);
```

after removing this line it is working now for me.